# Add legend to each point with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to add a legend to some points in my Excel chart as you can see below.

[image: chart with legends on points]

I can control each point color, however I can't find how to edit this legend. (On the picture I created and edited it manually by adding a tag.)

I wanted to use something like `cht.Legend.LegendEntries(1).Value = "lol"`.

Comment: Are you referring to the chart legend, or you name in this way that Speech bubble shapes where you wrote "point" "2nd point"?

Comment: @FaneDuru Indeed I am talking about that speech bubble related to the two point not the chart legend. I don't know how it is called in the english version of Excel..

Comment: Are you able to find those specific points coordinates?

Comment: @FaneDuru yes I have the data ordered the way I want. That's why I can color them individually.

Comment: @FaneDuru oh no I'm definitely not willing to do that. But those shapes come from the tag you can add to display the X and Y of the point. I removed the X and Y and added some text instead. So these shapes you can see follow the chart and the points

Comment: So, try this: `.SeriesCollection(1).Points(r).ApplyDataLabels xlDataLabelsShowBubbleSizes
                .SeriesCollection(1).Points(r).DataLabel.Text  = "Your text"`   In a `With ... End With` of a Chart object. and `r` is the point..  Can you post your code to create the chart (editing your initial post)? I will show you where to put the lines if not clear enough...

Comment: @FaneDuru It works ! Thank you very much ! Can you post the answer so I can accept it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim chSer As Series, j As Long, i As Long, SerPoints As Points
Dim shCh As Chart
Set shCh = ActiveChart
With shCh
    For Each chSer In .SeriesCollection
        Set SerPoints = chSer.Points
        j = SerPoints.count
        For i = 1 To j
            SerPoints(i).ApplyDataLabels Type:=xlDataLabelsShowBubbleSizes
            SerPoints(i).DataLabel.Text = "Whatever" & i
        Next
    Next
End With
```

Correctly declaring `chChar` and `SerPoints`, can be very helpful. You can use VBA intellisense to see all `DataLabel` properties and not  only that...

For instance, you can add some definitions for so named labels on a column near the chart series and name it "DataLabels", then use the next code to automatically apply the contained strings:

```
Dim rng as Range
Set rng = sh.Range(sh.Parent.Names("DataLabels").RefersToRange.Address)
 'and add the data in this way:
SerPoints(i).DataLabel.Formula = "=" & sh.Name & "!" & sh.Cells(rng.Row + i - 1, rng.Column).Address
```